# How to create custom Fields that display in Payment Method Section?

Tags: magento2.3.4

I want to show a custom field that displays in payment section but not as a payment method,
I have searched many extensions but all are using a payment method, but I want that type extension, it has 2 textboxes and checkbox, and when we click on the checkbox and 2 textbox was a display, and also other payment method work with this  extension,

like below image,
[image: to]

**I want to create Custom Section in Payment method Section.**

**Please give me some suggestion, i don't want full code, but i want some idea, how can i do that.**

Comment: i have created one extension but it was using payment method, so checkbox was not work instead of radio button

Comment: you have to override each and every payment methods to display it

Comment: @HarshJayswal but i need only one section, not all payment method, as you can see in image, that checkbox section is display, that i want

Comment: Please help me on this, i need really any suggestion on this

Comment: i have not done this but let me check if i found some solution for it